# Ambethia Recaptcha unable to rerender after Ajax form submission in Webkit browsers

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webkit, recaptcha

I have an Ajax form in my Rails app that contains the Recaptcha markup as provided by the helper in the Ambethia Recaptcha gem:

```
recaptcha_tags :ajax => true
```

On submit, the form hits a create action, which responds with the create.js.erb that contains the following:

```
$('#message-form').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render('message')) %>");
```

The 'message' partial contains the same form markup that was originally rendered, including recaptcha_tags, but may also display if there were errors in the validation at this point.

In Firefox, the form gets re-rendered and displays a refreshed Captcha.  But for some reason, in Webkit browsers (Safari and Chrome), the 'dynamic_recaptcha' Recaptcha element gets emptied, as if Recaptcha.create(public_key, element_id) never gets called.

In the Safari Developer console, I am able to call Recaptcha.create(public_key, element_id) and regenerate a Captcha.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i had the same problem and couldn`t get it to work with the recaptcha_tags in webkit browsers.

finally i followed the official guideline and wrote it like that (in HAML) ....

---

1. in the layouts head tag:

   ```
   = javascript_include_tag "http://api.recaptcha.net/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"
   ```
2. in the partial which was rendered
   via ajax:

   ```
   #dynamic_recaptcha
   :javascript
     Recaptcha.create('YOURPLUBLICKEY', document.getElementById('dynamic_recaptcha') , '')
   ```

---

http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html

Comment: The link of recaptcha_ajax.js seems to be dead. I found this one http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js

Answer (score 1):

if anybody is having this issue, ajax: true did the trick for me. Im using rails 3.2.13 and recaptcha 0.3.5

```
=recaptcha_tags(display: {theme: 'clean'}, ajax: true)
```

Comment: don't forget the escape_javascript like so:$("#recaptcha_div").html("<%= escape_javascript( recaptcha_tags(display: {theme: 'clean'}, ajax: true) ) %>")

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by the following method:

putting the scripts that won't load by ajax at runtime in head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
```

Optionally the theme:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var RecaptchaOptions = {"theme":"clean"};</script>
```

Then calling Ajax.Updater with **evalScripts** option at **true**:

```
new Ajax.Updater('example_div', '/example', { parameters: {text: $F('example_text')}, evalScripts: 'true'});
```

Answer (score 0):

## in HTML file.

recaptcha_tags(ajax: true)

## in AJAX request

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/users/sign_in",
  type: "POST",
  data: { 
 
  email_id: user_email_id,
  password: pwd,
  type: login_type,
  browser_det: browser_details,
  login_type: "firebase",
  "g-recaptcha-response": grecaptcha.getResponse()
  }
```